# Z-Index Issue With Child Element

Tags: css, z-index

I'm having issued with the z-index property on a little chatbox that I've been working on.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uLDBp

Both elements are positioned aboslutley, and the only way to get the hide button to position itself behind the chatbox is to give it a z-index of -1, however that makes it un-clickable.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd take the button out of the chat box div and put them in a wrapper.

Comment: I've done that now, and use position: static instead of absolute on the wrapper, which works better with the hiding animation from JS. However i'm still having the same problem. -EDIT- I've got it sorted now, I moved the link after the div in the html.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this person has addressed your problem in an elegant manner

[Overlapping div making links unclickable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4445355/overlapping-div-making-links-unclickable)

Another optional solution I came across that seemed created was setting the button behind and then put another div element on top of both of them with a transparent background that can handle your clicks

Comment: Thanks I've got it sorted now.